# From A to B to C to D

Tags: prepositions

Let's assume that a lifecycle of a software development is requirement specification -> development -> testing -> validation -> maintenance.

Now, may I say that "our tool will help in the entire lifecycle of a software development **from requirement specification, to development, to testing, to validation, to maintenance**"?

Is this from...to...to...to is a correct formulation? Are there other options?

Comment: I would change "requirement specification" to "gathering specs."

Comment: My question is mainly about the "from" and "to".

Comment: The from and to used in your sentence is understandable.

Comment: "Let's assume that **the** lifecycle of [a] software development is...". And I am sure that the chain of 'to' can be broken with 'through' or 'thru', and with 'and'. But do you even need to do that? Developers know what the life cycle of their product is, so rather than explain what they already know, focus on *what* you can do.

Comment: @WeatherVane the software development is just an example, I wanted to know how to use from...to... with several elements.

Comment: So it is proof-reading? I tried to say "vary it". From [requirement] specification through development to testing and validation, and then maintenance.

Comment: This is a common type of phrase, it's fine.

Comment: @WeatherVane, that's a better option.

Answer (score 1):

The repetition of “to” is clumsy, as the poster is clearly aware. Another option would be just to use a colon and commas:

> “Our tool will help in the entire lifecycle of software development:
> requirement specification, development, testing, validation and
> maintenance”.

It is a little less clear here that this is a sequence of events (not really a cycle, but perhaps that is IT usage), but obvious enough, I think.